# Is there anyway to get this table data into iOS app?

Tags: objective-c, json, google-chrome

I work with a company who outsources their website. I'm trying to retrieve data from the site without having to contact those who run it directly. The table data I'm trying to retrieve can be found here:

http://pointstreak.com/prostats/scoringleaders.html?leagueid=49&seasonid=5967

My methodology thus far has been to use google chrome's Developer Tools to find the source page, but when I filter under the network tab for XHL, only the info of the current games can be found. Is there anyway to scrape this data (I have no idea how to do that; any resources or direction would be appreciated) or another way to get it? Am I missing it in the developer tools?

If I had to contact those who run the website, what exactly should I ask for? I'm trying to get JSON data that I can easily turn into my own UITableViewController.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just load the page source and parse the html.

Depending on your usage there may well be a copyright issue, the page has an explicit copyright notice so you will need to obtain explicit permission for your use.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot find the source page. Can you recommend any way to get it, or somehow have you managed to do it yourself with that URL (for the love of god I hope you say yes!)? Someone else told me: "It seems like the scoring leaders table is inserted into a script tag with php. See source line 318 of scoringleaders.html. The line starts with var team_source = [ { label: "Bloomington (USHL 2014/2015)", ..."

Comment: You have a URL in the question, it worked for me. It seems that some times an ad is displayed but on another load the ad is not present. The ad also has a link to the score page.

Comment: OK hold on--this is great. Can you explain just how you found it? I'd really appreciate it. I can only find source data for the scoreboards at the top and not the "scoring leaders" table.